# Why is there software that doesn't support certain platforms?

Tags: portability

I noticed a **huge portion** of software apps only support Windows and not Mac or Linux. I understand that there might be an API that they're using that only exists on a certain system. In this case, why don't programmers use cross-platform APIs instead, that have portable frontends that interact with non-portable backends? Are there any benefits to using non-portable APIs over portable ones?

Comment: Typically you develop software for the platform your users are on. If your users are only on platform X, why bother with other platforms?

Comment: Apple and Microsoft were not really interested in crossplatform applications in the past, applications only available for Windows or iOS help them to sell more licenses of their OS or their hardware. This has changed somewhat over the last few years by demands of the market and a shift in where those companies gain their most revenue.

Comment: In my experience, there is no such thing as a true cross platform API except for some very basic things that are possible because hardware essentially works the same way. Even the standard C library might work differently in some edge cases on different platforms. Cross platform APIs are hard to make, hard to use.

Comment: Especially with regard to GUI frameworks, you have two options: "native" (different on every platform), or "crossplatform" (same on every platform .. but looks different from all the native apps!). These are inherently in tension. Currently there seems to be a convergence on Electron style desktop web apps.

Comment: @Ccm - I don't know, I think Qt is pretty good and I would also consider it easy to use.

Comment: Microsoft learned the hard way that users don't like cross-platform GUI look-and-feel with the disaster that was Word 6.0 for Mac. Microsoft ported the entire Windows UI stack to Mac and then simply rebuilt Word 6 for Windows to run on Mac. Users consistently gave the product bad reviews and preferred WordPerfect and ClarisWorks. From then onwards Word/Office for Mac is a completely different and unrelated product to Office for Windows until Office 365 where they finally had acceptance on both platforms for software that look like web apps.

Comment: Why would a novelist write a book in English and not in every other language as well?  There's even "APIs" (e.g. Google Translate) that can translate that novel into a bunch of other languages.  Will it be a perfect translation?  No, in fact, it will probably be terrible, unless you have human editors fluent in both English and the target language for every language you want to publish in.  It's the same thing with software.  Making something compatible with every platform takes a *lot* more work, even with cross platform APIs (which most are not).

Comment: @GlenYates the bug tracker of QT says otherwise. Cross platform API work on a very limited set of functionalities. As soon as you need to interact with any sort of hardware acceleration, things go south.

Comment: I'm guessing your "huge portion" does not include web apps?  Writing for the web is essentially cross-platform, and is probably so common for that very reason.

Comment: To support @pjc50's comment, the disparities between GUIs and their focuses on different platforms cannot be understated - what one platform pushes for "user experience" reasons, another platform might ignore entirely and go in a different direction. To code the GUI portion uniquely for each platform adds a huge amount of effort, which has to be considered cost wise when talking about which platform to target. Using MS Windows key bindings and interaction approaches when on Mac ends up just being jarring (looking at you, Blender), but the trade off for the app not doing that is time and money.

Comment: A standard is developed _because_ there's a need for unification of individually separate options. Any question on "why did they not use the unifying standard?" is inherently answered either because (a) the standard did not yet exist or (b) they weren't interested in the standard. "Why didn't they use X?" is a generally off topic question that is going to attract close votes as it requires either speculation or Word of God (i.e. an answer from the person who made he decision) to answer, both of which are off-topic for StackExchange.

Comment: @OutstandingBill writing for the web is only crossplatform until you meet someone who doesn't use Chrome. (Most of the IE6 users have migrated now, but Safari is still different often enough) But yes, it's *almost* crossplatform enough that it's become very popular to do even desktop apps with web technologies.

Comment: So a question with over 100 up votes gets closed, presumably by moderators. This, along with uncommented down votes is the reason I seldom answer questions.

Answer (score 59):

There is some gross missunderstanding about APIs here.

Platform-specific APIs are the norm, with platform-independent APIs being the exception. At least historically.

As a developer, if you want to make a platform-independent application, you have to reimplement significant portion of your application, or even the full application, for each platform, because the APIs are fundamentally different. Basic memory work, IO manipulation, processes, threading, all of these behave fundamentally differently on different platforms and systems. And your application needs to adapt to that.

Feature-full cross-plaform APIs are a relatively new phenomenon, especially for specific types of applications. Creating a cross-platform console application or web application has been possible for a while. This was because despite APIs being different, there were ways to abstract them away, along with proper platform adapters. There was less focus on cross-platform UI applications, because most UI frameworks are both complex and different enough, that creating a common API is both time-consuming and creates issues with platform-specific features missing.

Comment: I was a little confused to about this sentence: *"Creating a cross-platform console application or web application was possible for a while."* I know web applications are cross-platform. I'm not sure about console applications, though.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Strictly speaking, console applications are basically command line apps that output text. Given that, yea, standard I/O has been around for a *long* time.

Comment: There is no such thing as cross-platform APIs; there are only platforms that run on other platforms. When you make an app with Java you are not making a cross-platform app; you are making a Java app. And the Java APIs are not cross-platform, e.g. they don't work in Electron or .NET. But there are Java emulators for Windows, Mac and Linux, which are the platforms you actually care about.

Comment: @user253751 That is kind of pedantic. In this case, the implication was that "platform" means different HW+OS . And that multi-platform means application that can run across different HW (desktop, mobile) and OS (Windows, Linux, Mac, Android) either from single binary or compiled from single source.

Comment: @Euphoric It's not pedantic at all. Many people think there is some fundamental difference between Java software and Win32 software, but this is not true.  The only "law of physics" difference is that Java software can be run on Win32 with the use of the appropriate emulator. But Win32 software can also be run on Linux with the use of the appropriate emulator.

Comment: It's worth understanding that being cross platform isn't simply a choice. It's work. It's work to the point of needing to argue that you have the right to use an open source API in front of the US Supreme Court. It's never just using the right tools.

Comment: Is this why JVM languages are so popular? Does the JVM handle all the API differences for you?

Comment: @SomeGuy it handles some. Others, not so much. We can't even agree how to encode [NaNs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050133/are-the-bit-patterns-of-nans-really-hardware-dependent/25050550#25050550).

Comment: @user253751 Would you consider Qt a platform? It allows cross platform native apps. Also Wine Is NOT an Emulator; Wine on its own can only run binaries on the same hardware they were compiled for.

Comment: @jaxad0127 Qt is 90% of a platform, and WINE is not a **CPU** emulator but it's absolutely a Win32 emulator.

Comment: I'd add that on top of reimplementing a significant portion of your application, you're likely to find yourself reimplementing a lot of the internal libraries that you built for previous applications that you may be re-using in a current application; if you have extendable code that generates an application window ,for example - now you're not re-using it, but reimplementing it to make an application window on multiple platforms. It's that, but for all the other parts you mentioned in your answer as well.

Comment: @user253751 There are not cross-platform ABIs (except there kind of are in some cases, such as the old IBCS ABI), but there very much _are_ cross-platform APIs. POSIX is probably the most famous example (no sane person would argue that macOS, AIX, HP-UX, z/OS, and VxWorks are the same platform, but they all provide the standard POSIX API).

Comment: wrong. Platform specific APIs have always been the norm, not the exception.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn if you do call these cross-platform APIs, there are ABIs which work the same way and surely they should be called cross-platform ABIs.

Comment: @user253751 : Just because Java is not a "true cross-platform API", it doesn't mean they don't exist. For example, Qt is a good candidate, as it's not based on emulation, you can really build platfrom-specific programs with it.

Answer (score 21):

One major component mentioned in the comments on your question is cost/benefit.  Developing a cross-platform application or API is more expensive up-front than a single-platform piece of software.  Every API or library has, *at least*, slightly different behaviour on different platforms, or very different behaviour, or there's not one single library for all platforms and you have to mix/match with an adapter in between.  The operating system has different rules about where files go and what access there is.  The drivers for hardware that you are using have slightly different behaviour.  Users of the different platforms have different expectations.  
 For example - Linux users will tend to expect their software to be open-source or will be unlikely to adopt. 
 Apple users expect a certain level of UI/UX experience that has to keep up with the current desktop paradigms that may shift.  
Phones and tablets have much less display space and usually limited resources...

In addition, validation and testing of a multiplatform solution is expensive.  You'll need access to a lot of VMs and/or hardware, and each platform takes about as much testing time as all the others.

So if a company makes the vast majority of their revenue on the most common platform  then investing in the others may not be worth it from a cost/benefit perspective.  I have worked on closed-source, specialized cross-platform libraries, and the team did a great job creating a codebase that could be used with equivalent functionality across Windows, OS-X and iOS (with some tentative Linux builds too).  However, in the end there was no real revenue from any of the platforms besides Windows, so maintenance of the other platforms petered out.

Comment: A good example of a technical platform difference is that on Android, if you want your app to run constantly in the background (as opposed to waking up every now and then) you **must** display a notification in the notification bar that says so. Otherwise it will randomly stop your app running.

Comment: Perfect answer. The way I used to put it to customers who were insistent that I support their chosen platform was that I could add a mac version of my Windows software at substantial development costs, and add, say 10% more users. Or I could put that same effort into a new Windows version and double my sales. Business wise, it just doesn't always make sense to support multi-platform software. Especially in the past when multi-platform gui tools weren't as widely available as they are today.

Comment: @GrandmasterB Right now I use a commercial software product that has a backend built with Java, and the front end is rendered by whatever web browser you have installed.  They install their own version of Java, and the web browser has to support all their needed technologies.  But as a result, it is a cross platform application that runs the same on Windows, macOS and Linux.  However, it was built from the ground up that way.

Comment: When talking about cost, you can't forget about *testing*.  You generally support multiple version of each OS, plus with Linux you have different distros and alternative architectures (like ARM or RISC). Your QA workload will very quickly explode to 10x what it was for a single platform, which in turn costs you both time and money.

Comment: @bta - you make a very good point. I remember just the hardware cost of testing (we were daft and didn't outsource) was significant.  I'll add it.

Comment: @PeterM I've worked on ground-up cross platform solutions and they were still more expensive than the equivalent single-platform one  by at least one order of magnitude.  If you have the resources, it's fantastic, great fun and a massive learning experience, but it *is* expensive for commercial projects, so you do have to do the cost/benefit analysis.

Comment: In addition to testing, there are deployment costs: can't write iOS apps without owning a Mac and paying a subscription, for example.

Comment: @JorisTimmermans I'm not saying it is easy or cheap, but when it's done with intent it's impressive.  It's also probably helped by the fact that the company who did it is also the most responsive commercial software company that I've encountered.  I once went from reporting a bug to having a patch in 2 hours - and I don't even have a support contract with them.

Comment: @PeterM That is an impressive turnaround!  The lead devs I've worked with on cross-platform projects have been extremely impressive, knowledgeable, and willing to offer fair critique to help everyone else grow in their understanding of what it means to be cross-platform, properly.

Comment: @JorisTimmermans They also have 100% training/documentation online for free, and you can download and run the complete product for free.  It just runs for 2 hours when unlicensed, and you can restart as many times as you want.  OTOH they are stuck with Python 2.7 as their scripting language (actually Jython) /s

Comment: @PeterM IMO, its better to use a system designed for multiplatform development rather than cobbling something together like that. For example, there's Electron, if a web based interface like that is desired - no need for Java to be involved.

Comment: @GrandmasterB If it was a simple single user app I would agree with you.  However, it is a large, modular client/server application that allows for multiple users to both perform real-time editing and data visualization, as well as communications with multiple external devices and databases.

Answer (score 14):

There are two major impediments:

1. Lack of standardization between platforms
2. The need for "write once test everywhere" even when using cross-operating system languages like Java or C/C++.

For instance, HTML and JavaScript are very much standardized, and you can write a web application on an operating system that will be accessed transparently from multiple user operating systems. Before I retired I worked in such an environment developing (in Java/J2EE) on Windows and deploying on Linux. This was just about hassle free. Compatibility problems had more to do with browser quirks than problems with the underlying user operating systems.

But consider developing a GUI application on Windows and expecting it to work on Windows, Linux, MacOS, Android and IOS. Quite simply you are up for a huge amount of testing, and will need a number of hardware platforms to test on. Google, Microsoft and Apple have little interest in making compatible systems. There are frameworks like GTK that help, but you will still be up for a lot of testing time, and the result often does not feel "native" to the platform.

Also, there are good reasons for developing differently for different platforms. For instance, in the past web applications often had tens of fields on a form. This works great on a big monitor, but is close to unusable on the small screens of phones. Similarly the availability (or not) of touch-screen features can mean an application needs lots of user friendliness testing before release.

There are some bright spots. Frameworks like Cordova, React, Flutter etc ease the task of building Android/Mobile/Web applications, and this is a hot area of development.

Answer (score 14):

Building an application is the same as playing Tetris with weird shaped pieces. Every piece must fit perfectly together for it to work.

The simplest example is some hardware with an application running on it.
For this to work, the interface between the hardware and application must match.

[image: Hardware and application]

In reality this is a cumbersome process. Who wants to control all details of the hardware on their own? If you embark on this journey you are either never going to get done, or you have a very niche usage on some very specific hardware.

Therefore, we use a standard program to manage all the hardware for us - an Operating System.
This ensures the interface between the hardware and the application. But as can be seen, now the application must conform to the interface of the Operating System. A lot easier, but still a requirement.

[image: Hardware and OS]

Why can't I just run the application on all Operating Systems you ask.
Well, the interface of the Operating Systems are not the same for a number of (very good) reasons.

[image: Different OS]

This means that if you want your application to run of two different Operating Systems you must build your application twice. Three times for three Operating Systems. You get the idea.

[image: Different OS and you]

Someone else identified this issue and tried to solve it. An example of this is Unity. They have made a number of different versions which can run on different Operating Systems. Suddenly, your application no longer needs to worry about which OS is underneath. However, now you've tied yourself to Unity.
Is this better? Depends on your scenario.

[image: Middleware]

Of course, not everyone wants to use Unity (or some similar solution). So they either have to have one version for each Operating System or simply choose only to support a few select of them.

There are of course a multitude of variations of this - not all hardware is the same, there can be several additional layers and so forth.

(I've tried a more visual approach here with fewer technical details, so perhaps some parts are more easily understood by those with no technical insight into this.)

Comment: this is straight forward, even caveman understand. programs are about preparing for possibilities. we pay overhead to place an if statement. if you know what to expect you can optimize. writing code is the fun part but a lot of dev is linking pieces together and telling them to be friends.

Answer (score 5):

As others well-pointed, in the end, the decision comes down to a convenience and cost/benefit problem.

For example, in the mobile development sector, cross-platform implementations are a real thing. In my experience working for a consultancy specialized in that field, I can say that for many customers the first option is a cross-platform solution and the reason is obvious: costs.

Developing 2 native apps is not only more expensive, some times it's not worth it due to the market segmentation. If the segmentation is decompensated, a cross-platform application is reasonable. When costs are not a reason, the law can be. For instance, public organizations want to reach all citizens regardless of individual platforms.

> Are there any benefits to using non-portable APIs over portable ones?

In line with the previous arguments, cross-platform apps suffer from interoperability constraints with the underlying platform.

Platforms and cross-platform frameworks/API evolves at different paces. Platforms change first, and after a while cross-platform frameworks adopt these changes, but not always successfully or in time which causes losses due to the opportunity cost.

Feature missing (sometimes) forces developers to implement walkarounds that rarely make for a good UX; it's also considered boiled plate code which is not always portable to newer versions of the cross-platform framework.

Comment: From my experience (Xamarin and React Native) while it's easy to create a basic IOS+Android app, for anything complex, getting it to the high level of polish our customers expected on both platforms has ALWAYS turned out to take 2X more work than writing 2 separate apps, due to all the edge cases from differences and the amount of time it took to fix those bugs. We finally bit the bullet and refactored to native apps and the bug rate went down like 5X. On the back-end it's different, Node.js works fine wherever.

Comment: We usually recommend native when the app is clearly in the center of the business or the app is the real product. It's not the case for public orgs or small clients, but when the UX is key, we never implement hybrid or cross-platform apps

Answer (score 4):

Even cross-platform languages such as, say, Mono tend to behave slightly differently on different platforms.

In this example, between Linux, Windows and Android the user interfaces render slightly differently, especially for UIs built using a Winforms designer, so they require some tweaking before they're entirely satisfactory.

(And in this specific example, I doubt that Mono has had enough use on the Mac or the M1 to be quite free of defects.)

Moreover, differences in display geometry and user-interaction services, e.g. small vs. large screen, mouse vs. touchscreen, presence or absence of a physical keyboard, dictate different design decisions.

So while it's easier than it was fifteen years ago, to write for multiple platforms still isn't merely a design choice; it entails some effort.

Answer (score 1):

Because an API is only a way to say what you want done. If what you want is not possible on the platform, it is pointless implementing the API as it would merely report that your command failed. Sometimes the underlying behaviour is just different.

For example, on Linux, you can delete a file while it is open and the program which has it open can keep using the file until it closes it. During this period, the file does not have a name. On Windows, you can't delete a file that is open. However, the capability to use a deleted file is exploited on Linux by programs that need a temporary file that will be guaranteed to go away even if the program, or thw whole operating system, crashes. This ability is used when updating software, which is why Windows needs to reboot after so many updates, but Linux does not. Windows has a mechanism whereby a file can be deleted at the next reboot, so updates have to use this for files that are in use rather than simply replacing them.

And some differences may affect user interactions. On Linux, if you use a windowing system derived from X11 (which you almost certainly do), there are two different types of copy and paste. I can highlight text with the mouse, and them middle click elsewhere and the text is copied - no need to hit ctrl-C or choose a "Copy" menu command. This uses the "primary selection". But there is also a copy and paste just like Windows - highlight text, hit ctrl-C, click elsewhere, hit ctrl-V. This is called the "clipboard". The two mechanisms are separate, so after copying one thing with ctrl-C, I can copy another by highlighting and paste whichever I like. In fact there's also a secondary selection, but I have never felt the need to use it.

To give an analogy, an API is like a language. But however well a New Yorker learns French, they won't see the Eiffel Tower in New York. They could climb the Statue of Liberty instead, but that would still be a different experience.

Comment: Except the highlight and middle click copy/paste is a left-over from the console only days and framebuffer days, not X11.

Comment: @ivanivan irrelevant where it comes from, it's there and it limits X in serious ways.

Answer (score 0):

There already many answers and many good reasons for the situation. But there is a point that is missing. Developers training and IDEs and tool that make too easy to include libraries and functions that then lock the final result to an OS.

IDEs that generated part of the code started at the end of the '90 with Borland. But Borland quickly succumbed to Microsoft Visual Studio and with it came the practice of using tools that made things easy, but at the same time included vendor lock ins.

After that the problem involved the frameworks whose role in the applications became increasingly important. Some frameworks encourage platform independence some do the opposite. The initial choice will have consequences on the final product. But the initial choice often depends on the skills and the training of the developers involved.

There is no free lunch. When it is too easy and too quick to develop an application there is going to be a downside somewhere. Some king of vendor lock in is often one of those downsides.